# Pass variable to WCF custom encoder?

Tags: c#, wcf, encoder

When building a WCF client to generate and send out a SOAP message, I want to log a snapshot of the whole message include all the header information to my database before sending out through the wire. It looks like at Message Encoder Classes I have a snapshot of the message in its WriteMessage method. I don't know WCF framework architect that well so I am not sure how I can pass a variable into the custom encoder? Essentially I want to pass in my database's sql rowkey so we can log a snapshot of this message related to the particular sql row record. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you must create a class that implements IDispatchMessageInspector interface.

This interface has two methods:

**AfterReceiveRequest** - hitted when you receive a message request

**BeforeSendReply** - hitted when you send a response

You can get both request and reply and, so you can save in your database.

And you can add a header to your message, so you can use this information as the "variable" you want to use.

Here is a example you can follow:
http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article121

**UPDATED**
Just including the other solution, using a custom MessageEncoder, here is an example:

```
 public class MyTextMessageEncoder : MessageEncoder
 {

        public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)
        {
            StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string msg = sreader.ReadToEnd();

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            var message = Message.CreateMessage(reader, maxSizeOfHeaders, this.MessageVersion);
            // Here I add my MessageHeader
            var poweredBy = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
                            "X-Powered-By", "", "MyApp");

            message.Headers.UnderstoodHeaders.Add(poweredBy);
            return message;
        }

 }
```

Comment: Maybe I should make it more clear, I realized that I may be asking confusing questions.. I am building a WCF client to send out message. And the snapshot of SOAP message we got at message inspector doesn't include some of the SOAP headers (from/to), and more importantly it doesn't include the security headers (SAML etc). That's why I want to do it at message encoder level. Thoughts?

Comment: In both methods you can add headers to request or reply. You can use a code like this:
var myHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
                            "X-Powered-By", "", "YourName");
reply.Headers.UnderstoodHeaders.Add(myHeader);

Comment: I really don't think message inspector is the place to do as it won't have the security tokens. I know in message encoder we have all the information (more close to the wire) but then I am not sure how to pass variable into message encoder.

Comment: If you want to work in encoder you'd probably wrote your own custom message encoder class,right? Your class must inherits MessageEncoder class and override some methods. The ReadMessage method is a good place to add the headers, because this method receives array of bytes an returns a Message object, where you can add your MessageHeader.